# how to call a component inside a component in react dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

As per the image if i click on Business setup only the red border area to be render .. Header and side menu bar to be static. Business setup is an component ... By end i need to render the components dynamically in red border area

In "TriggerPath" function getting the name and path of component and i have given an id for that render part "himsapp" where to render the component.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
            class PersistentDrawer extends React.Component {

    state = {
        open: false,           
        title:"Dashboard"
      };
            const drawer = (
                  <Drawer
                    variant="persistent"
                    anchor={anchor}
                    open={open}
                    classes={{
                      paper: classes.drawerPaper,
                    }}
                  >
                    <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
                      <div className="menuBar-title">
                        <span style={titleStyles.title}>ALGAEH</span>
                        <span style={titleStyles.organisation}>ERH</span>                                   
                        <IconButton onClick={this.handleDrawerClose} style={{color:"#fff"}}>
                          {/* {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />} */}
                          <MenuIcon />                                                  
                        </IconButton>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="hptl-phase1-sideMenuBar">
                      <Paper style={paper_style} className="paper" elevation={4}>
                        <div className="sideMenu-header">{MenuListItems}</div>
                      </Paper>
                    </div>
                  </Drawer>
                );

    TriggerPath(e) {
        for an exapmple path = "/BusinessSetup"
        const path = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("path");
        let screenName = e.currentTarget.innerText.replace(/\s/g, "");

        this.setState(
          {
            toggleSubMenu: true,
            title: screenName,
          },()=>{
            let component ="<" + this.state.title + " />";  

            component,document.getElementById("hisapp")
          });



  }

    render(){
            return (
              <div className={classes.root}>        
                <div className={classes.appFrame}>
                  <AppBar
                    className={classNames(classes.appBar, {
                      [classes.appBarShift]: open,
                      [classes[`appBarShift-${anchor}`]]: open,
                    })}
                  >
                    <Toolbar disableGutters={!open}>
                      <IconButton
                        color="inherit"
                        aria-label="open drawer"
                        onClick={this.handleDrawerOpen}
                        className={classNames(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
                      >
                        <MenuIcon />
                      </IconButton>
                      <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap>
                        {this.state.title}
                      </Typography>
                    </Toolbar>
                  </AppBar>          
                  {drawer}          
                  <main
                    className={classNames(classes.content, classes[`content-${anchor}`], {
                      [classes.contentShift]: open,
                      [classes[`contentShift-${anchor}`]]: open,
                    })}
                  >
                    <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
                      <div className="container-fluid">
                        <Typography >  
                          <div id = "hisapp">
                            <Dashboard />              
                          </div>                  
                        </Typography>
                      </div>
                    </main>            
                </div>
              </div>
            );
    }
        }
```

Comment: You can do that by rendering `{props.children}`, see this for details:
https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You should look for some path props value that you can get in dashboard component. Based on that decide what to render. write a helper function which will contain a switch, rendering the correct component. Are you using some kind of statemanager like redux ?. If yes that can give you easy access to current state of application. Read react documention for further help